# 2 Find statements in one function in CakePHP 2.1

Tags: cakephp-2.0

Hi I'm currently working on a project and was wondering if it was possible to do two find functions in cakephp? 
For example I am making a sports news website and I am grouping the news articles as top story, understory and headline.

What I want to do is retrive top stories so i can highlight these as the prominent story and then understory will be beneath as a lesser story and then headlines will be the least important.

This is what I have so far

```
   function latestnews() {

$articles =  $this->Article->find('all', 
    array('limit' =>3,
    'order' => 
        array('Article.date_created' => 'desc')));
    if(isset($this->params['requested'])) { 
         return $articles; 
         } 
            $this->set('articles', $articles); 

    $articler = $this->Article->find('all', 
        array('Article.type' => 'topstory',
            'Limit' => '1'
    )); 

        $this->set('articles', $articler);

}
```

however this doesn't seem to work, it doesn't limit the $articles function but instead echos all the data in the table.

in the view im doing a standard foreach statement to echo the data and I get thrown a undefined variable error.

Is what i am saying even possible or should I create different functions and then use them as elements?

Thanks for any input in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using two find methods in one function I instead chose to simply create different functions and use them as elements for example...

```
function premiershiptopstory() {

            $pltopnews = $this->Article->find('all', array(
                    'conditions' => array('Article.league' => 'premiership',
                    'Article.type' => 'topstory')));
                        if(!empty($this->request->params['requested'])) {
                        return $pltopnews;}
                        $this->set('article', $pltopnews);  


            }
```

However in the view you must request the action otherwise you will get thrown an error, to request the action simply use this line of code...

```
 <?php $pltopnews = $this->requestAction('/Articles/premiershiptopstory');
```

Hope this helps others!

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the associationship with itself dynamically. Try this code:

```
function latestnews() {
    $this->Article->bindModel(array('hasMany' => array('TopStory' => array('className' => 'Article',
                                           'foreignKey' => false,
                                           'conditions' => array('Article.type' => 'topstory')
                                           ),
                               'Highlight' .....
                               )));
    $articles =  $this->Article->find('all',
                      array('limit' =>3,
                        'order' =>  array('Article.date_created' => 'desc')));
    if(isset($this->params['requested'])) {
        return $articles;
    }
    $this->set('articles', $articles);

    $articler = $this->Article->find('all',
                     array('Article.type' => 'topstory',
                           'Limit' => '1'
                           ));
    $this->set('articles', $articler);

}
```

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

@Arun Nope that didn't seem to work, I get this error, `Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Article.type' in 'where clause'` also I've tried to put it in an element with its own function and I then get thrown this error...

Notice (8): Undefined variable: data [APP/View/Elements/Articles/topstories.ctp, line 5]
Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP/View/Elements/Articles/topstories.ctp, line 5]
Notice (8): Undefined property: View::$Paginator [CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 806]
Fatal error: Call to a member function prev() on a non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kickoff/app/View/Elements/Articles/topstories.ctp on line 21

The controller code is the following...

```
function topstories() {
    $this->paginate = array(
        'conditions' => array('Article.type' => 'topstory'),
    'limit' => 2,
    'order' => array(
        'date_created' => 'asc'
    )
    );
    $data = $this->paginate('Article');
    $this->set(compact('data'));

}
```

I find this error confusing as if I don't put this in an element and in a view instead it works perfectly! however in an element not so perfect :S 
any ideas as to why this is the case??

Comment: As in the code in your question show it like "type" is a field in your Article table. Use that field instead of "type" based on which you can identify the topstory, headline... etc. Thanks